# Am I losing precision in manually entered equations?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, rounding

I am using the following code to calculate the two solutions of a quadratic equation in the variable *t*.

```
Solve[PCLz + t*PDCz == -0.002344*(PCLx + t*PDCx)^2 + 0.0266*(PCLx + t*PDCx) - 0.0744, {t}, Reals]
```

The two solutions for *t* are shown in the attached image.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I now insert values for the variables. PCLy and PDCy are unused.

```
PCLx = -0.108300;
PCLy = -3.357973;
PCLz = -0.037214;
PDCx = 0.113764;
PDCy = 0.0;
PDCz = 0.993535;

Solve[PCLz + t*PDCz == -0.002344*(PCLx + t*PDCx)^2 + 0.0266*(PCLx + t*PDCx) - 0.0744, {t}]
```

with solutions

```
 {{t -> -32648.6}, {t -> -0.0404809}}
```

now to copy the image.

```
k = 0.00170648*(3325.*PDCx - 586.*PCLx*PDCx - 125000.*PDCz);
b = PDCx^2;
d = PDCx^4;
l = (-6241.*(PDCx^2 ) + (5.86*10^6)*PCLz*(PDCx^2) + (3.325*10^7)*PDCx*PDCz - (5.86*10^6)*PCLx*PDCx*PDCz - (6.25*10^8)*(PDCz^2));
n = -1*(l/d);
tneg = (k/b) - 0.00853242*Sqrt[n]
tpos = (k/b) + 0.00853242*Sqrt[n]
```

giving tneg = -32648.6 and tpos = -0.00221659 which don't match the previous solutions. I suspect I am losing precision when I enter the solutions myself. Why don't the solutions for *t* match in the two cases?

problem solved 9/23/2022 15:30 EST:
I change the definitions as follows:

```
q = 0.002344;
s = 0.0266;
v = 0.0744;
a = -q*PDCx^2
b = s*PDCx - 2*q*PCLx*PDCx - PDCz
c = -1*(PCLz + q*PCLx^2 - s*PCLx + v)
PCLx = -0.108300;
PCLy = -3.357973;
PCLz = -0.037214;
PDCx = 0.113764;
PDCy = 0.0;
PDCz = 0.993535;
```

and

```
tpos1 = (-b + Sqrt[(b^2) - 4*a*c])/(2*a)
tpos2 = (-b - Sqrt[(b^2) - 4*a*c])/(2*a)
```

and I have the correct results. I suppose this is a lesson in allowing rounding events to occur. The question is solved, but not yet answered/explained.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smanu.png

Comment: I am getting an error running your first code. But the displayed numbers on the screen do not show the full decimal points.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHLxe.png)  I am not sure if this is what you are asking or not. Look for `PrintPrecision` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958531/mathematica-output-formatting  again, I am not sure if this is what you are asking or not.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I set the PrintPrecision ->10, however this did not change the result of the code. What error is happening for you?

Comment: Screen shot of error. (from clean kernel) V 13.1 on windows  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQTVQ.png)  may be front end bug. I do not know what it means.

Comment: Another screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2oo5.png)

Comment: `PrintPrecision ->10` only affects the display, not internal computation. I thought this is what you were asking about.

Comment: No, I mean the disagreement between the two results for t calculation.

Comment: fyi, I posted separate question on the error in your code   [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273877/typeset-is-not-graphic-directive-error-message-from-solve-command) since you go not get this error, but I see it. It might be a version issue.

Comment: note: I am reading https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html and may be on the right track.